# How to get the length of the string array in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, split, inputstream

I tried to get the length of the string array from split string like this

```
tombol.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String isi="";
        try{
            InputStream inputstream=getAssets().open("test.txt");
            int size=inputstream.available();
            byte[] buffer=new byte[size];
            inputstream.read(buffer);

            isi=new String(buffer);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] isiv2=isi.split("\n");
        int size=isiv2.length;
        txt.setText(size);
    }
});
```

I split the string and tried to get the length of it in

```
String[] isiv2=isi.split("\n");
int size=isiv2.length;
txt.setText(size);
```

but it returns an error

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error you posted is most likely not caused by the code you posted.

Comment: It is caused by the code he provided.

Comment: NB Don't write code like this. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. And don't ignore the value returned by `read()`. It should be `int count = inputstream.read(buffer);
isi=new String(buffer, count);`

Comment: @MC Emperor it is caused by the code i posted

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I will remember it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use

```
txt.setText(size);
```

This tries to execute [`TextView#setText(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)).

This interprets the size as resource id and not displays the integer.

When you use

```
txt.setText(String.valueOf(size));
```

it passes the size as `String` which invokes [`TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) which displays the size as `String`.

Comment: didnt realize that. thanks! problem solved